# map two lists of dictionaries into one single list

Tags: python

i have a question please;
i have two lists like this

```
my_inital_list=  [{"name": "Tom", "age": 30},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 25},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 97}]

my_second_list =   [{"name": "Pam", "quant": 10},
  {"name": "Mark", "quant": 5},
  {"name": "Tom", "quant": 7}]
```

can you please explain to me how can convert theme to something like this without using nested loops

```
my_final_list=  [{"name": "Tom", "age": 30,"quant": 7},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 25,"quant": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 97, "quant": 10}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Why can't you use a nested loop? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: as i mentioned, nested loops for ... for but i'm looking for something more pythonic, i'm trying to imrove my self

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to avoid the nested for-loop used for matching:

```
# create a lookup dictionary 
lookup = {d["name"]: d for d in my_second_list}

# merge the dictionaries using lookup
res = [{**d, **lookup[d["name"]]} for d in my_inital_list]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 30, 'quant': 7}, {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 25, 'quant': 5}, {'name': 'Pam', 'age': 97, 'quant': 10}]
```

The `lookup` dictionary maps the values of the `"name"` in `my_second_list` to it's own dictionary:

```
{'Pam': {'name': 'Pam', 'quant': 10}, 'Mark': {'name': 'Mark', 'quant': 5}, 'Tom': {'name': 'Tom', 'quant': 7}}
```

then you can use it to fetch the data by name, for example:

```
lookup["Pam"]  # returns lookup["Pam"]
```

then simply iterate over each dictionary on `my_initial_list` using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona) the corresponding dictionaries using the expression below:

```
{**d, **lookup[d["name"]]}
```

Comment: can you explain to me please

Comment: @bellamimolinka Updated the answer

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thank you so much